# An EC2 instance behind a load balancer is not terminating after reboot but load balancer is going out of service

Tags: amazon-ec2

There is single EC2 instance deployed behind a ELB using Cloud Formation and now I am trying to add cron jobs to crontab by updating CF stack, however after updating the stack I rebooted the server but the changes are not reflecting on the server.

It seems like the application on the server is only rebooted not the OS of the server. When I checked status of ELB after reboot, instance state is out of service and instance state on the EC2 tab is showing running.

Note: There is no autoscaling group attached.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlow! I made some minor edits to make the question a bit easier to read, otherwise good question well asked.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your application on EC2 instance is listening on the port mentioned in loadbalancer.

Comment: It is listening and LB is coming up after reboot , but i am facing difficulty in doing OS level changes through cloud formation template. When i reboot after updating the stack  only the application deployed on the server is rebooting not the whole server.